# Openshift Existing Build Configs is not shown with jboss tools

Tags: git, openshift, jboss-tools

I am testing wildfly deployment on openshift v3 with JBoss Tools. This reference site is https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_developer_studio/10.1/html/getting_started_with_container_and_cloud-based_development/developing_for_the_cloud_with_openshift_3#build_logs

Generating Wildfly pod is successful. And Git source is set with this url, https://github.com/gladiator67/test-openshift.git and windows folder. This is my folder image.

[image]

[image]

The problems is Import an Existing OpenShift 3 Application into the IDE. I try to import Application. But Existing Build Configs is not shown. I can not import any source project into Openshift explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Now I see what you want to do.
OpenShift 3 has slightly different concept. What you want to read about is something called Source to Image (S2I). It's basically builder image, which clones your git repository, builds it, creates an docker image and pushes it into openshift docker registry.

In devstudio, you will do something like this:

1) Have OpenShift connection, create project, create new application

2) On the first page of New OpenShift Application wizard, select builder image you want (I used jboss-eap70-openshift:1:4)
[image]

3) On the second page, fill out your git repo URL, your branch and context dir:
[image]
4) The rest of pages should be OK with default settings.

After hitting Finish, the build pod should start. It will clone your repository, build it (using maven) and create docker image with your application. After this image is pushed to openshift's internal registry, the build pod is terminated and new pod should be created (this is your app).

One last step is missing. When app is being build, it uses maven "openshift" profile, so add it to your pom.xml: https://github.com/rhopp/openshift-test-helloworld/commit/f32c6a87163374a85009b9148338a82ac150a422

Now there are two options:

1) Every time you commit something into your repository you can start new build by hand or

2) Configure webhook (https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/builds.html#webhook-triggers)

And for faster development there is third option: Using Server adapter, which just rsync the build classes directly into pods without need to commit and push your changes and waiting for the buid to finish: https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/os3_startusing.html#deploy_app

If you want something, you can catch me (or the JBoss Tools developers) on #jbosstools irc channel on freenode.
Radim

Comment: I do appreciate for your answer. I am sure it will be really helpful to openshift users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve. 
But if you want to access build log and you don't see build pod in OpenShift Explorer, that's probably because the build already finished.

If you want to see build log anyway, you have to look in Properties View (there is generally a bit more info than in OpenShift Explorer). You can do this by right clicking the project (icon with the people) and select "Properties". This should bring Properties View to focus. There you can select "Builds" tab and there should be all finished (and unfinished) builds.

Hope this helps.
Radim
 [image]

Comment: Thank your for your reply. My problem is building war files in github folder does not occur. Pls, have a look at the first pic. In previous version 2, I could check building war files and deployment of war in openshift wildfly was successful. However in current openshift v3 and jboss tools, I have no idea how to build github web source codes in openshift wildfly.